# How to marshal a .Net interface over a socket?

Tags: c#, interface, marshalling

I have an interface in C#, something like this:

```
interface ITest
{
    int Method1(int something);
}
```

All methods have parameters of basic types (integer, string, enum).

Now I want the implementation and the client to run on different machines communicating over a socket. What I could do manually is to make an implementation like this:

```
class Test : ITest
{
    int Method1(int something)
    {
        m_Serializer.Serialize(something, m_Socket);
        int result = (int)m_Serializer.Deserialize(m_Socket, typeof(int));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to automate it, i.e. to generate such a wrapper for a given interface automatically?

I could generate it manually via `Reflection.Emit`, but that's quite complex. Any easy way?

Comment: Generate it how?  are you expecting a socket server to receive some data and generate (via Reflection.Emit) an implementation of ITest as it receives the data?

Comment: @Peter Ritchie Generate an implementation that will serialize it in a format "method name" "argument1" ... The server side would have an instance of my actual implementation and would call the methods via reflection.

Comment: @IvanShcherbakov Phew, I thought you were thinking of serializing code over the wire... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WCF (Windows Communication Foundation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) would be what you're looking for. It does pretty much exactly this - it does however have a somewhat steep learning curve.

I like to think of it as a framework that automatically generates a network "protocol" that is defined by your interface - the service contract. The "protocol" is also independent of the underlying network transport - there are bindings for raw TCP, HTTP, HTTPS, all with different use cases in mind.

You never have to actually care about what the network traffic actually looks like at the protocol or byte level - the whole lot is done for you seamlessly.

Clever stuff, worth learning.

**Complete example of a WCF client and server over plain TCP, with no config files (all programmatic)**

Create a class library which will be shared between two other programs, your client and server, containing an interface.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyApi
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello(string s);
}
```

In program one, the server:
Add a reference to the class library above.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class MyApi : IMyApi
{
    public string SayHello(string s)
    {
        return "Hello " + s;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    var api = new MyApi();
    var svcHost = new ServiceHost(api, new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:12345/MyService"));
    svcHost.Open();
    Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
}
```

Program two, the client:
Add a reference to the class library above.

```
static void Main()
{
    var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:12345/MyService");
    var cf = new ChannelFactory<IMyApi>(binding, endpoint);
    var client = cf.CreateChannel();

    Console.WriteLine(client.SayHello("Tom")); // output on the console should be "Hello Tom"
}
```

Comment: Don't use WCF however, if you have even the slightest possibility of using it outside of a .NET environment. That is... not so fun.

Comment: WCF over REST over HTTP(S) is fine with a non .NET environment. Just use a different binding (`WebHttpbinding`). There's a pretty decent example here: http://saravananarumugam.wordpress.com/2011/03/04/simple-rest-implementation-with-webhttpbinding/

Answer (score 2):

While you could just serialize the data yourself (see [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) and deserialize on the other side, there are better options.

[Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) is a technology in the .NET framework which handles this for you.  It automatically manages all of the communication (sockets) as well as the transfer of objects across multiple transport technologies.